# Flutter bottom navigation bar with side drawer navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I needed both the navigation drawer and the bottom navigation so I did add a custom Navigation drawer in my project also did add and shown the bottom navigation bar but the problem i'm facing is i can only display it but unable to set the onTap functionality to it and navigate around pages. As a reference i do have pasted the sample code.

```
class SideBarLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _tab_list =[

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
        create: (context) => NavigationBloc(),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<NavigationBloc, NavigationStates>(
              builder: (context, navigationState) {
                return navigationState as Widget;
              },
            ),
            SideBar(),
          ]
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (currentIndex){
          _currentIndex = currentIndex;

        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF478DE0),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.assignment),
            title: Text('Quotation'),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF478DE0),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
            title: Text('Payments'),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF478DE0),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text('Profile'),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF478DE0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure of what you're trying to achieve, `Scaffold` has a `drawer` property, please check that.

Comment: I have implemented the Sidebar() to bring out the sidebar navigation drawer also i needed the bottom navigation bar hence i did add the widget bottomNavigationBar but the onTap functionality tonavigate page is not working